# Mimicking the Gmail app label listing

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to build a layout for my `ListView` items similar to the Gmail app's listing of labels, where it has the label text on the left and the count to the right.  What I have mostly works, except with long text.  What I have results in the text overlapping the count.

This is what I'm trying to mimic:

[image]

As you can see, the bottom label isn't wrapping where the top label is (read below for more details on this).

When both labels have a count, the count lineup on each row:

[image]

With what I have there should be a 3 showing for the last item but it's getting overlapped.  Also, I'd like the "count" `TextView` to lineup on each row the same way the Gmail app is (center, right aligned, I guess?):

[image]

Layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="1"       
>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
    />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical" 
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I know when you're using `layout_weight` you're supposed to set the `layout_width` to 0px, however, this results in every row being cutoff at the same spot.  I only want the text wrapping if it goes longer than the count `TextView`.

I am not good with Android layouts, I think they are extremely frustrating to work with, so this may be something easy.  Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using Weights, define `layout-gravity`, not `gravity`, for both text fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to prevent the views from overlapping by using a `RelativeLayout` instead of your `LinearLayout`, using the `layout_toRightOf` or `layout_toLeftOf` XML attributes to position the views relative to one another.

Comment: Won't this cause the "count" `TextView` to align to the right of the "text" `TextView`, which would result in the listing being out of alignment from one row to the next?  I'd like the "count" `TextView` on each row to line up.

Comment: If that's the only attribute you use to control the positioning, yes. Perhaps combining it with something like `layout_alignParentRight` will produce the desired effect? I'm tragically away from compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I needed to add `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/count"` to the first `TextView`which Ernir answered above